# how to Rewrite Single Page url in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite only 1 specific URL
from

```
http://www.domainname.com/index.php?route=payment/axis/callback
```

to

```
http://www.domainname.com/payment/axis/callback
```

I tried these two from stack overflow, I don't know why its not working

1st one :

```
RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?route=payment/axis/callback    [NC,L]
```

2nd one :

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?route=payment/axis/callback payment/axis/callback [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> 4) Rewriting yoursite.com/user.php?username=xyz to yoursite.com/xyz
>
> Have you checked zorpia.com.If you type http://zorpia.com/roshanbh233 in browser you can see my profile over there. If you want to do the same kind of redirection i.e http://yoursite.com/xyz to http://yoursite.com/user.php?username=xyz then you can add the following code to the .htaccess file.
>
> `RewriteEngine On
>    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
>    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1`

See the full page [here.](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: kindly check my question i am try to do from http://www.domainname.com/index.php?route=payment/axis/callback to http://www.domainname.com/payment/axis/callback

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `.htaccess` with `RewriteRule`, since there are often problems with it. **A simple workaround** (with PHP redirect):

```
<?php
if($_GET['route'] == 'payment/axis/callback') {
    header("Location: http://www.domainname.com/payment/axis/callback");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use h0ch5tr4355's workaround or you can try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=payment/axis/callback$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} index.php
RewriteRule (.*) /payment/axis/callback [NC,QSD]
```

If you instead of a rewrite would like it to redirect to the new url you can add `R=301` to the flags of the RewriteRule.

Comment: I will appreciate you if you guide me that can i add two rewrite condition is one .htaccess file. My htaccess file working properly but i need to rewrite in same file. I want to rewrite this URL (http://www.example.ae/index.php?route=common/thispage) to (http://www.example.ae/thispage)

Comment: @Mr.Developer The entries in the answer does exactly that. If a RewriteRule is preceded by multiple RewriteCond lines, all the lines have to match for the RewriteRule to be active (unless you use the [OR] flag). Of course you will have to change the parameters and URLs to match your needs.