# how to load and handle the meta data on server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, whatsapp

I want to know that how we handle the meta data on web, for example a share a link on whatsapp like this [image]

After that whatsapp load its meta data against this link on the basis of user id .
I want to know that what function is called on server side to get user image against the user id like this[image]

What's operation perform on server side to get the meta data on the basis of user id. in first image userId is **arslankathia** 
**Help me.**

Comment: It has nothing to do with metadata -- you're passing the username as part of the URL itself. Snapchat simply parses the URL.

Comment: can you please guide me how they parse the url? in the form of link or etc

Answer (score 2):

Whatsapp gets this information using the og(Open Graph) meta tags.
These tags contain information to display cards like these.

An example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Card Title">
```

If you want to create such cards yourself you can read up on the og protocol here: http://ogp.me/
You can dynamically create the meta tags based on the user id using PHP if you want to.

The routing magic can be accomplished using for example Laravel (Lumen) in PHP. You can specify what function handles what url format.
Another option is to use .htaccess rewrites like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33231875/8751302.